# same proxy pass config not working on both instances

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, proxy

i have a config /etc/nginx/sites-available/test that only proxies one server the first (blog) and returns a nginx 404 on the second (api) I have tried trouble shooting but to no avail

i tried checking for any syntax or spelling errors i copied the working directive and only replace the server path and name i deleted one directive and it works flawless but not when both are there

```
upstream blog {
    server 127.0.0.1:3001;
}

upstream api {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    
    server_name local.net www.local.net;
    
    location /blog/ {
        rewrite ^/blog(.*)$ $1 break;
        proxy_pass http://blog/;
        include proxy_params;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    
    server_name api.local.net;
    
    location /api/ {
        rewrite ^/api(.*)$ $1 break;
        proxy_pass http://api/;
        include proxy_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: The 404 could be returned by the API server, not nginx.

Comment: what *trouble shooting* have you tried, just so we don't waste our time and yours offering the same troubleshooting steps you've already tried

Comment: Hi @JaromandaX Thanks for the reply... I tried interchanging the proxy routes i.e taking blog to where api is which results in api working and blog returns 404

Comment: Hello @GeraldSchneider Thanks for replying... No the error is the default nginx error... However if i change the api block to the blog one it works but then blog returns 404

Comment: so what you're saying is that `127.0.0.1:3000;` is the issue

Comment: Hi @JaromandaX  not exactly, the port is not the problem because as I pointed out earlier if i move the server on port 3000 to be the first nginx server block it would work but now the 3001 would return a 404 and vice versa

Comment: I misunderstood what you meant by interchanging proxy routes, I thought the issue is that not matter which port / "path", it's the API service that returns 404

Comment: @JaromandaX no problem am new to this and had no idea how to place and explain my issue

Comment: so, it's not the uopstream api at server 127.0.0.1:3000; that is always returning 404, it's whatever `server` is configured later in the config?

Comment: @JaromandaX its not the api server since that would return a json 404 and the one am facing is the default nginx 404 despite which server i put in the second block if i move the api block up it works but then my blog returns nginx 404

Comment: i ended up going with reverse proxying via individual configs under `/etc/conf.d/*` i.e 

`/etc/nginx/conf.d/example.com.conf` 






```server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://destination;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
}```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ended up going with reverse proxying via individual configs under `/etc/conf.d/*` i.e

> /etc/nginx/conf.d/example.com.conf

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://destination;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
}
```